# How to find this part and repair my Honda Civic 2014 rear window

Tags: part-identification, diy, window, rear, weather-dependent

Car is Honda Civic 2014 Sedan

This plastic part in my car's left rear window got broken. I am not sure how to search for the replacement as I do not know what this part is called. Could anyone please help me?

How this part look like:

[image: part location]

Also some of the weatherstrip is missing. I am wondering if there is specific weather-stripping for the car or if I can get generic model and apply it myself.

Comment: It's not at all clear what part(s) you are showing and where they fit on your car.  Please update your question with a view that shows the part where it fits into the vehicle.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have added a new picture

Comment: It's not listed separately but as part of the whole door in the [catalogue](https://www.hondapartsonline.net/v-2014-honda-civic--ex-l--1-8l-l4-gas/body-air-conditioning--rear-door-panels). Are you sure it's removable (without it being broken)?

Comment: @Unimportant, yes it is broken off. I have seen skme videos online where people remove it for reinstalling weather stripping.